# MediatR handlers registration fails on integration tests requests

Tags: .net, mediatr

I'd like to perform integration tests on one of my microservices using TestServer. I use default IoC container to register dependencies. My startup is a copy of microservice startup without database healthchecks services, etc. To register MediatR handlers I use:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(
                x => x.FullName.Contains($"test.{type.ToString()}") || x.FullName.Contains($"test.Common")).ToArray();

services.AddMediatR(assemblies.GetAssemblies);
```

Besides, my AppTestFixture class looks like:

```
public class AppTestFixture : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                    .UseTestServer();
            });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Unfortunelly, this piece of codes works excellent on real production, it means that MediatR handlers are registered correctly, but if I execute integration tests, then 'register handlers not found' exception is thrown. Why handlers are registered correctly on real environment, but on test not? How to register MediatR handlers on test environment?

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(
                x => x.FullName.Contains($"test.{type.ToString()}") || x.FullName.Contains($"test.Common")).ToArray();
```

Run one single test under debug or pipe out the contents of:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

And I would imagine that none of the where clause(s) fit when running your integration test(s) but that is hard to say without more info. See what the output is when you run a test, that will be the key.

So this

```
services.AddMediatR(assemblies.GetAssemblies);
```

Does not register your handlers as the result is null/empty.

If that does not give you the issue then you could try and register the minimum of handlers manually. You can then see if it is the registration process that is causing the issue or not. So manually register like this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ISomeType), typeof(SomeType));
```

or

```
services.AddScoped<ISomeType, SomeType>();
```

If you do this you are at least taking away any reflection stuff from GetAssemblies() from the process. I would always try an isolate a single test and debug that.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The case I experienced these issues with MediatR was because I have multiple (two) WebApplicationFactories where the exact same exception was thrown.

When I changed the order of the instantiation it worked perfectly - but this should not matter of course - so I dived in a bit deeper.

What happens is that, because the assemblies are loaded lazily into the `AppDomain` (which is shared), the list of loaded assemblies will grow when more assemblies are required by the application.

In my case, the list for WebApplicationFactory A contains `IRequest` types and their corresponding handlers. When WebApplicationFactory B started, the `AddMediatR()` call failed, because it could not find the Handlers for the `IRequest` types that belonged to WebApplicationFactory A.

Since the naming of the projects in our solution are consistent I fixed it by checking the name of the type, whether it started with the same based on the passed generic type, like this:

```cs
private static IServiceCollection AddMediatR<T>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    var manifestModuleName = typeof(T).Assembly.FullName;

    var assemblyPattern = new Regex(@"(Organisation\.(.*?))\.");
    var match = assemblyPattern.Match(manifestModuleName!);

    if (!match.Success) return serviceCollection;

    var assemblyName = match.Groups[1].Value;

    var applicationAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(assembly => assembly.FullName != null && assembly.FullName.StartsWith(assemblyName))
        .ToArray();
    if (applicationAssemblies.Any())
    {
        serviceCollection.AddMediatR(applicationAssemblies);
    }

    return serviceCollection;
}
```